# Scrape HTML tables with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the upstream and downstream values for each channel from our ISP Cable Modem.

I cannot get the data to display correctly.
I want the data to output in a normalized CSV format for logging.

Here is the code I have, but it's woefully inadequate.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Collect and parse first page
page = requests.get('http://192.168.100.1/Docsis_system.asp')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

# Pull all text from the proper section in the page
#signal_value_list = soup.find('tbody')
signal_value_list = soup.find('table', {'summary':'Downstream Channels'})

# Pull text from all instances of <td> tag within align div
signal_value_list_items = signal_value_list.find_all('td')


# Create for loop to print out all values
for signal_value in signal_value_list_items:
    sigval = signal_value.contents[0]
    print(sigval)
```

the page I'm trying to parse is located at this link as a TXT file:

[Download it here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=03704782423247144705&t=0370478242324714470548335)

[screenshot of the modem page with tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7EsQ.jpg)

I'm willing to go some other direction to get this data, but I wass hoping that I could get this done far easier than it has turned out.

Anyone have thoughts?

Comment: Can you give an example of the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what the data you wish to parse is, but assuming that we're talking about (for instance) the downstream channels' power levels and SNR, one possible solution is the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
# Collect and parse first page
# page = requests.get('http://192.168.100.1/Docsis_system.asp')
with open('files/modem-page.html') as f:
    text = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')

# Pull all text from the proper section in the page
# signal_value_list = soup.find('tbody')
signal_value_list = soup.find('table', {'summary': 'Downstream Channels'})

# Pull text from all instances of <td> tag within align div
signal_value_list_items = signal_value_list.find_all('td')
res = {}

# Create for loop to print out all values
for signal_value in signal_value_list_items:
    try:
        channel_string = signal_value.attrs.get('headers')[0]   # get name of channel
        property_string = signal_value.attrs.get('headers')[1]  # get name of property
        value_string = signal_value.text    # get actual value
        if channel_string not in res:
            res[channel_string] = {}
        res[channel_string][property_string] = value_string
    except TypeError as e:  # for all irrelevant elements
        continue

with open('res.csv', 'wb+') as csv_file:    # add column names to your liking before this
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for key, value in res.items():
        writer.writerow([key] + [value[prop] for prop in value])
print res
```

A similar code can be written for upstream data as well (I'll leave that to you). Possible improvements are sorting the channel names (I'm using a dictionary so the order is random) and adding column names. Hope this helps